# How to prevent from changing a Windows Service Startup Type?

Tags: windows-services

I created a Windows service and installed into users machine. 
That windows service is very important and I do not want to user can change its startup type to "disable".
It seems "Plug and Play" service can disable the Startup drop-down listbox.
How can I make same behavior for my windows service?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it has to do with setting the appropriate permissions on the registry key. But a user with sufficient permissions can do anything. If this is for a business application, I would try to stick to using group policy or user permissions. If this is for a commercial application then I would expect a lot of upset users and malware detection.

Comment: >>But a user with sufficient permissions can do anything.
Yes. If a user which has administrative permissions wants to change this through registry, I did not mind. I just want to it is not very easy to change it in the drop-down listbox.