# How to restrict user from changing the win service startup type

Tags: windows, winapi, service, windows-services

I need to restrict user from changing the startup type of service.

e.g. Following two windows services do not allow user to change their startup type;
 1. "**Group Policy Client**" and 
 2. "**Plug and Play**"

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent from changing a Windows Service Startup Type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249614/how-to-prevent-from-changing-a-windows-service-startup-type)

Comment: When your users are administrators on local computer, they can do anything they like. Any attempt to restrict them is futile. You can obfuscate the configuration and make it harder, but administrators will find their way to circumvent your settings. Make your users non-admins.

Comment: @SevaTitov; I am administrator but system still do not allow me to access or modify following two services (Win7) and their start values in registry,
1. Group Policy Client (gpsvc)
2. Plug and Play (PlugPlay)

Comment: @SKAR, as an administrator, you can easily bypass this limitation. There are many ways to do this. One of them is [launching cmd window as Local System](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/11/27/271063.aspx?Redirected=true), where you can do pretty much anything. Another is taking ownership of registry key and resetting ACLs on it.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and with a small change I achieved my goal. I just changed the TRUSTEE and assigned required access to them.

```
// Build the ACE.

BuildExplicitAccessWithName(&ea, TEXT("ADMINISTRATORS"),
    SERVICE_START | DELETE,
    SET_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE);
```

Thanks,